# Reverse Layout Order of Flow

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I'd like to have `Flow` in which the objects are added from the left to the right, but each row is aligned to the right.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
Flow {
    width: 400
    anchors.right: parent.right
    spacing: 2
    Repeater {
        model: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
        delegate: Button {
            text: modelData
            width: (83 * (model.index + 1)) % 100 + 30
        }
    }
}
```

I have the `Flow` aligned to the right, but the rows in it will always start at the `Flow`s left edge. I could set

```
layoutDirection: Qt.RightToLeft
```

which would align the rows to the right, but the order of the items would be reversed as well.

If I reverse the model (in this example possible by calling `reverse()`, with a `ListModel` I would need a reversing `ProxyModel`) `a` would be to the left, but the rows are out of order.

How could I achive something like that?

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root;
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        z: -1
        color: "#80000000"
        width: flow.width
        height: flow.height
        anchors.centerIn: flow
    }

    Flow {
        id: flow
        width: 400
        anchors.right: parent.right
        spacing: 2

        Repeater {
            id: repeater
            property real remainingRowSpace: flow.width
            property real indexOfFirstItemInLastRow: 0

            model: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q']
            delegate: Rectangle {
                property real buttonWidth: (83 * (model.index + 1)) % 100 + 30

                color: "#80000000"
                width: buttonWidth
                height: childrenRect.height

                Button {
                    x: parent.width - width
                    text: modelData
                    width: parent.buttonWidth
                }
            }

            onItemAdded: {
                var spacing = parent.spacing

                // Check if new row.
                if (item.width > remainingRowSpace) {
                    // Increase width of first item push row right.
                    itemAt(indexOfFirstItemInLastRow).width += remainingRowSpace
                    // Reset available space
                    remainingRowSpace = parent.width
                    // Store index of item
                    indexOfFirstItemInLastRow = index
                    // Don't need to subtract spacing for the first item
                    spacing = 0
                }

                remainingRowSpace -= (item.width + spacing)

                // Handle when no more rows will be created.
                if (index === repeater.count - 1) {
                    itemAt(indexOfFirstItemInLastRow).width += remainingRowSpace
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's not a very versatile or dynamic solution, but it works.

Comment: This is a nice solution, for the case, that after the creation everything stays static. If the model changes, it is necessaray to relayout everything. Changes of the size of the `Item`s will also need recalculation of everything. Still it is a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

> **This is still a work in progress but might still be usable for some people**

Just as the solution of *Tony Clifton*, it uses a `Repeater` and it's `onItemAdded`-method, but uses `Qt.binding` to keep things *more* dynamic. **It is not superior** to *Tony Clifton*s solution and the choice might depend on the usecase.

Upsides:

- Dynamic to changes of the individual `Item`-width
- Dynamic to the width of the *ReversedFlow*

Downsides:

- Fills the bottom row first. First row might not be full (for some usecases this might be better)

Both solutions wont work, when used with a `ListModel` and a new entry is being `insert()`ed. Both solutions should work, when the model is completly replaced (e.g with `JSArray`s and a manual call of `modelChanged()`).

Both solutions are no `Flow`s in the sense, that you can throw in arbitrary objects as a `Repeater` takes care of the layout. So the `Repeater` has to create the `Item`s. I did not get it working with an `ObjectModel`. Getting rid of the Repeater will be my last concern.

```
Item {
    id: root
    visible: false
    width: 400
    height: (rep.count > 0 ? rep.itemAt(0).y * -1 : 0)
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    property real spacing: 5
    Item {
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.left: parent.left
        Repeater {
            id: rep
            model: ListModel {
                id: bm
                ListElement { text: "a" }
                ListElement { text: "b" }
                ListElement { text: "c" }
                ListElement { text: "d" }
                ListElement { text: "e" }
                ListElement { text: "f" }
                ListElement { text: "g" }
                ListElement { text: "h" }
                ListElement { text: "i" }
            }

            onItemAdded: {
                console.log(index, item, itemAt(index - 1))
                item.anchors.right = Qt.binding(
                            function() {
                                if (rep.count === index + 1) return parent.right
                                var neighbor = rep.itemAt(index + 1)
                                if (neighbor.x - item.width - root.spacing < 0) return parent.right
                                return rep.itemAt(index + 1).left
                            }
                            )
                item.anchors.bottom = Qt.binding(
                            function() {
                                if (rep.count === index + 1) return parent.bottom

                                var neighbor = rep.itemAt(index + 1)
                                if (neighbor.x - item.width - root.spacing < 0)
                                    return neighbor.top
                                return neighbor.bottom
                            }
                            )
                item.anchors.rightMargin = Qt.binding(
                            function() {
                                return (item.anchors.right === parent.right ? 0 : root.spacing)
                            }
                            )
                item.anchors.bottomMargin = Qt.binding(
                            function() {
                                return (item.anchors.bottom === rep.itemAt(index + 1).top ? root.spacing : 0)
                            }
                            )

            }
            delegate: Button {
                text: modelData
                property int count: 0
                width: (83 * (index + count + 1)) % 100 + 30
                onClicked: {
                    count++
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: debug
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: 'transparent'
        border.color: 'red'
    }
}
```

The idea behind this, is to initialize bindings of the anchors when the objects are added, where I anchor each `Item` to either the right side or it's successor, if there is enough space.
I also anchor the bottom of the `Item` to it's successors bottom, if it is next to him, or to it's top, if it starts a new row. If it has no successor, it will be anchored to the bottom of the parent.
The latter fact, makes this strange construct with two enclosing `Item`s necessary. The outer on will really enclose everything, and dynamically grow, but this can't be the one, I anchor the whole chain to, as I anchor to the bottom. If I would change the `height` depending on the `childrenRect.height` I would end in a binding loop with strange effects, as the y-values of the Items would not stay constant. Initially it would work, but when the the items move due to size changes, it would break.